# TypeError: _mediapipe_face_mesh__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.FaceMesh is not a constructor

Tags: next.js, electron, mediapipe

I wish to integrate mediapipe into a NextJS + Electron application. However, upon importing `FaceMesh` and "attempting" to use it, i am getting the following error on `@mediapipe/face_mesh`:

[image]

For context, I am using a NextJS + Electron with the help of the library `Nextron`. I have tried the methods proposed in the following issues:

1. https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/1946
2. https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/2546
3. https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/3796

but i am not getting any results.

Inside `FaceMeshComponent.js`:

```js
import React, {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import Webcam from "react-webcam"
import { FaceMesh } from "@mediapipe/face_mesh";

function FaceMeshComponent() {
    const webcamRef = useRef(null);
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {   
        const faceMesh = new FaceMesh({locateFile: (file) => {
            return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/face_mesh/${file}`;
        }});

        faceMesh.setOptions({
            maxNumFaces: 1,
            refineLandmarks: true,
            minDetectionConfidence: 0.5,
            minTrackingConfidence: 0.5
        });
    }, [])

   return <div>...</div>
```

Appreciate any help i can get!

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
import * as FaceMesh from '@mediapipe/face_mesh';
```

instead of what you have as import for you have for face_mesh currently.

Also, when you create the object instance, use:

```
const faceMesh:FaceMesh.FaceMesh = new FaceMesh.FaceMesh (...)
```